# how to block empty referrer in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

how to block empty referrer in .htaccess? i've read this [topic](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/) to deny visitors by referrer but I want to deny referrer if it is empty. Thanks

Comment: so, people will not be able to share URLs to your web-site... nice

Answer (score 2):

To deny the empty referer, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

`RewriteCond`
 ition checks to see that the referer value is empty `^$`
 , if it is empty then the rule redirects to forbid the request.

Comment: thank you.. i actually arrived at the same code.. but now my problem is how to test it on my local server.. so i think i will have to figure it out...